# Script sencillo windows - pausas

Tags: script, batch

estoy haciendo un scrip troll .bat para pasarselo a un amigo y se asuste un poco. Este es el codigo que tengo, pero quiero que los mensajes de deleting disk, aparezcan poco a poco, cada segundo un mensaje nuevo.

```
@echo off
start %comspec% /c "mode 40,10&title Optimizador&color 1e&echo.&echo.Optimizing the computer. Please wait&pause>NUL"
timeout 4 /nobreak 

for /L %%b in (1,1,100) do (timeout 1 /nobreak echo Deleting disk C: %%b%%)
pause>nul && exit
```

Estoy probando a meter el timeout dentro del for, pero todo el rato me esta dando fallo:

```
 Type "TIMEOUT /?" for usage. ERROR: Invalid syntax. Default option is not allowed more than '1' time(s).
```

Muchas gracias

Comment: Yo usaba `ping localhost -n cantidad > nul` para hacer esas cosas. Digo cantidad, porque no es precisamente el mismo tiempo que va a tardar, la relación entre ellos es aproximadamente de 2 o 3 por segundo. Aún así hay mejores opciones

Answer (score 0):

con sleep se pueden hacer las pausas, en la terminal con 'man sleep' te aparece la forma de uso, por ejemplo con

```
sleep 3
```

el script espera 3 segundos.
 Espero te sirva.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar timeout para ello.

El uso es de timeout es:

```
timeout /t tiempo(en segundos)
```

Un parámetro opcional:

- `/nobreak` que impide que el tiempo de espera se pueda saltar con Ctrl+C.

Puedes incluir `> nul` al final de un comando para que no genere salida en pantalla.

Ten en cuenta que puede que tú amigo sea listo y cierre el script enseguida. Tu plan no habrá sido el más efectivo.

Para mejores resultados recomiendo que hagas un ejecutable hecho con un lenguaje de programación, por ejemplo C o C++. C# también es una opción aunque tu amigo debe tener la misma versión de .Net Framework que tu usaste para crearlo. Java también puede ser, la única pega es que tu amigo tiene que tenerlo instalado.

Fuente: Stackoverflow en inglés: [How to sleep in a batch file](https://serverfault.com/questions/432322/how-to-sleep-in-a-batch-file/432323#432323)